# Android exception java.io.IOException: last block incomplete

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I am working on decrypting a binary file encrypted in C# using Rijndael encryption method. The file is copied to an android device. The decryption logic works fine when run in a java based desktop test program. But it throws `java.io.IOException: last block incomplete` when run in android. I am using the code below.

```
public static void Decrypt(String fileIn, String fileOut, byte[] key, byte[] IV, long offset)  
{
// First we are going to open the file streams 
FileInputStream fsIn;
try 
{
    fsIn = new FileInputStream(fileIn);,,
    FileOutputStream fsOut = new FileOutputStream(fileOut);

    // create cipher object
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(IV));

    // create the encryption stream
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fsIn, cipher);

    // set a buffer and keep writing to the stream
    int bufferLen = KiloByte;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
    int bytesRead = 0;

    // read a chunk of data from the input file
    while ( (bytesRead = cis.read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) != -1)
    {
        // write to file  
        fsOut.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    } 

    fsOut.flush();
    // close streams 
    fsOut.close();
    cis.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

The key is generated by using the function

```
public static byte[] GetKey(String password, byte[] IV, int length)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
{
    // Length is kept 16 to make it compatible with all platforms
    SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec ks = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), IV, 1000, length*8);
    SecretKey s = f.generateSecret(ks);
    Key k = new SecretKeySpec(s.getEncoded(),"AES");

    return k.getEncoded();
}
```

I have gone through many posts on internet related to the topic. Based on that, I have made sure that I use byte array rather String. But still getting this issue.

Comment: It might be an encoding issue in `password.toCharArray()`. Can you check that the same key is generated on PC and Android?

Comment: seems that your key is different. check your key.

Comment: I am using the same password and salt to generate the key. During debugging I am able to see that the key generated in C# is not the same in Java. But the question is if the key is different then how it works on desktop? Also I had a similar function to decrypt a string and that works without any issues.

Comment: Guys, the key doesn't alter the size of the ciphertext. Of course getting the wrong key is an issue as well, but you shouldn't get "last block incomplete" because of it. It's more likely that the *binary* input is not the same (maybe text conversion such as altering end-of-line or appending a BOM was used during the copy).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Figured out the real problem. There is a header of 458 bytes in the input stream which is not encrypted. The actual code has a skip statement for CipherInputStream i.e. `cis.skip(offset)`. With AES encryption it was not matching with the block size. I increased the header to 464 which is a multiple of 16 and the issue is resolved.